# Routing, Navigation and State in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am attempting to refactor my app using the MVC paradigm.

My site displays charts. The URLs are of the form

- app.com/category1/chart1
- app.com/category1/chart2
- app.com/category2/chart1
- app.com/category2/chart2

I am using Apache Rewrite to route all requests to index.php, and so am doing my URL parsing in PHP.

I am working on the enduring task of adding an `active` class to my navigation links when a certain page is selected. Specifically, I have both category-level navigation, and chart-level sub-navigation. My question is, what is the best way to do this while staying in the spirit of MVC?

Before my refactoring, since the nav was getting relatively complicated, I decided to put it into an array:

```
$nav = array(
  '25th_monitoring' => array(
    'title'    => '25th Monitoring',
    'charts' => array(
      'month_over_month' => array(
        'default' => 'month_over_month?who=total&deal=loan&prev='.date('MY', strtotime('-1 month')).'&cur='.date('MY'),
        'title'   => 'Month over Month'),
      'cdu_tracker' => array(
        'default' => 'cdu_tracker',
        'title'   => 'CDU Tracker')
    )
  ),
  'internet_connectivity' => array(
    'title'   => 'Internet Connectivity',
    'default' => 'calc_end_to_end',
    'charts' => array(
      'calc_end_to_end' => array(
        'default' => 'calc_end_to_end',
        'title' => 'calc End to End'),
      'quickcontent_requests' => array(
        'default' => 'quickcontent_requests',
        'title' => 'Quickcontent Requests')
    )
  )
);
```

Again, I need to know both the current category and current chart being accessed. My main nav was

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($nav as $category => $category_details): ?>
    <li class='<?php echo ($current_category == $category) ? null : 'active'; ?>'>
      <a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $category . '/' . reset(reset($category_details['charts'])); ?>"><?php echo $category_details['title']; ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and the sub-nav was something similar, checking for current_chart instead of current_category.

Before, during parsing, I was exploding `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` by `/`, and breaking the pieces up into `$current_category` and `$current_chart`. I was doing this in index.php. Now, I feel this is not in the spirit of the font controller. From references like [Symfony 2's docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html#creating-the-front-controller), it seems like each route should have its own controller. But then, I find myself having to define the current category & chart multiple times, either within the template files themselves (which doesn't seem to be in the spirit of MVC), or in an arbitrary function in the model (which would then have to be called by multiple controllers, which is seemingly redundant).

What is the best practice here?

Update: Here's what my front controller looks like:

```
// index.php
<?php
// Load libraries
require_once 'model.php';
require_once 'controllers.php';

// Route the request
$uri = str_replace('?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && (!empty($_GET)) && $_GET['action'] == 'get_data') {

  $function = $_GET['chart'] . "_data";
  $dataJSON = call_user_func($function);
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo $dataJSON;

} elseif ( $uri == '/' ) {
  index_action();

} elseif ( $uri == '/25th_monitoring/month_over_month' ) {
  month_over_month_action();

} elseif ( $uri == '/25th_monitoring/cdu_tracker' ) {
  cdu_tracker_action();

} elseif ( $uri == '/internet_connectivity/intexcalc_end_to_end' ) {
  intexcalc_end_to_end_action();

} elseif ( $uri == '/internet_connectivity/quickcontent_requests' ) {
  quickcontent_requests_action();

} else {
  header('Status: 404 Not Found');
  echo '<html><body><h1>Page Not Found</h1></body></html>';   
}

?>
```

It seems like when month_over_month_action() is called, for instance, since the controller knows the current_chart is month_over_month, it should just pass that along. This is where I'm getting tripped up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I had almost the same trouble when was writing CMS-like product.
So I've spend some time trying to figure out how to make this work and keep the code more maintainable and clean as well.
Both CakePHP and Symfony route-mecanisms have a bit inspired me but it wasn't good enough for me. 
So I'll try to give you an example of how I do this now.

> My question is, what is the best way to do this while staying in the
>   spirit of MVC?

First, In general, best practice is NOT TO USE procedural approach with MVC in web development at all.
Second, keep the SRP.

> From references like Symfony 2's docs, it seems like each route should
>   have its own controller.

Yeah, that's right approach, but **it doesn't mean that** another route match can't have the same controller, but different action.

The main disadvantage of your approach (code that you have posted) is that you mix responsibilities and you're not implementing MVC-inspired pattern.
Anyway, MVC in PHP with procedural approach is just a horrible thing.

So, what exactly you are mixing is:

- Route mechanism logic (It should be another class) not in a "controller" and route map as well
- Request and Response responsibilites (I see that it isn't obvious to you)
- Class autoloading
- Controller logic

All those "parts" should have one class. Basically, they have to be included in index or bootstrap files.

Also, by doing so:

`require_once 'controllers.php';`

You automatically include ALL controllers per match (even on no-match). It actually has nothing to do with MVC and leads to memory leaks.
Instead, you should ONLY include and instantiate the controller that matches against URI string.
Also, be careful with `include()` and `require()` as they may lead to code duplication if you include the same file somewhere twice.

And also,

```
} elseif ( $uri == '/' ) {
  index_action();

} elseif ( $uri == '/25th_monitoring/month_over_month' ) {
  month_over_month_action();

} elseif ( $uri == '/25th_monitoring/cdu_tracker' ) {
  cdu_tracker_action();

} elseif ( $uri == '/internet_connectivity/intexcalc_end_to_end' ) {
  intexcalc_end_to_end_action();
```

It's extremely unwise to do a match using `if/else/elseif` control structures.
Okay, what if you have 50 matches? or even 100? Then you need to write 50 or 100 times to write `else/elseif` accordingly.
Instead, you should have a map and (an array for example) iterate over it on each HTTP request.

The general approach of using MVC with routing mechanism comes down to:

1. Matching the request against route map (and keep somewhere parameters if we have them)
2. Then instantiate appropriate controller
3. Then pass parameters if we have them

In PHP, the implementation would look like:

File: index.php

```
<?php

//.....

// -> Load classes here via SPL autoloader or smth like this

// .......

// Then -> define or (better include route map from config dir)

$routes = array(

    // -> This should default one
    '/' => array('controller' => 'Path_To_home_Controller', 'action' => 'indexAction'),

    '/user/:id' => array('controller' => 'Path_to_user_controller', 'action' => 'ViewAction'),   

    // -> Define the same controller
    '/user/:id/edit' => array('controller' => 'Path_to_user_controller', 'action' => 'editAction'),


    // -> This match we are going to hanlde in example below:
    '/article/:id/:user' => array('controller' => 'SomeArticleController', 'action' => )

);

// -> Also, note you can differently handle this: array('controller' => 'SomeArticleController', 'action' => )
// -> Generally controller key should point to the path of a matched controller, and action should be a method of the controller instance
// -> But if you're still on your own, you can define it the way you want.


// -> Then instantiate common classes

$request  = new Request();
$response = new Response();

$router = new Router();

$router->setMap( $routes );

// -> getURI() should return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$router->setURI( $request->getURI() ); 


if ( $router->match() !== FALSE ) {

  // -> So, let's assume that URI was:  '/article/1/foo'     

  $info = $router->getAll();

  print_r ( $info );

  /**
   * Array( 'parameters'  =>  Array(':id' => '1', ':user' => 'foo'))
   *        'controller'  => 'Path_To_Controller.php'
   *        'action'      => 'indexAction'
   */

   // -> The next things we are going to do are:

   // -> 1. Instantiate the controller
   // -> 2. Pass those parameters we got to the indexAction method   

   $controller =  $info['controller'];

   // -> Assume that the name of the controller is User_Controller
   require ( $controller ); 

   // -> The name of class should also be dynamic, not like this, thats just an example
   $controller = new User_Controller(); 

   $arguments = array_values( $info['parameters'] );

   call_user_func_array( array($controller, $info['action']), $arguments );  

   // -> i.e we just called $controller->indexAction('1', 'foo') "dynamically" according to the matched URI string

   // -> idealy this should be done like: $response->send( $content ), however

} else {

   // -> In order not to show any error
   // -> redirect back to "default" controller
   $request->redirect('/');

}
```

In my MVC-inspired applications I do route like this:

(Where I use Dependecy Injection and keep the SRP)

```
<?php

require (__DIR__ . '/core/System/Auload/Autoloader.php');

Autoloader::boot(); // one method includes all required classes

$map = require(__DIR__ . '/core/System/Route/map.php');

$request    = new Request();
$response   = new Response();

$mvc        = new MVC();
$mvc->setMap( array_values($map) ); 
// -> array_values($map) isn't accurate here, it'd be a map of controllers
// -> take this as a quick example


$router     = new Router();

$router->setMap( $map );
$router->setURI( $request()->getURI() );


if ( $router->match() !== FALSE ) {

    // -> Internally, it would automatically find both model and view instances
    // -> then do instantiate and invoke appropriate action
    $router->run( $mvc );

} else {

    // No matches handle here
    $request->redirect('/');
}
```

I found this to be more appropriate for me, after poking around Cake and Symfony.

One thing I want to note:

It's not that easy to find good articles about MVC in PHP. Most of them are just wrong.
(I know how it feels, because first time I've started to learn from them, like so many people do)

So my point here is:

Don't make the same mistake like I did before. If you want to learn MVC, start doing this by reading
Zend Framework or Symfony Tutorials. Even the ones are bit different, the idea behing the scene is the same.

**Back to the another part of the question**

> Again, I need to know both the current category and current chart
>   being accessed. My main nav was

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($nav as $category => $category_details): ?>
    <li class='<?php echo ($current_category == $category) ? null : 'active'; ?>'>
      <a href="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/' . $category . '/' . reset(reset($category_details['charts'])); ?>"><?php echo $category_details['title']; ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

First of all, don't concatenate the string, instead use `printf()` like:

```
<a href="<?php printf('http://%s/%s/%s', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $category, reset(reset($category_details['charts']))); ?>"><?php echo $category_details['title']; ?></a>
```

If you need this to be everywhere (or at least in many different templates), I'd suggest to this to have in a common abstact View class.

For example,

```
abstract class View
{
    // -> bunch of view reusable methods here...

    // -> Including this one
    final protected function getCategories()
    {
        return array(

            //....
        );
    }
}

class Customers_View extends View
{
    public function render()
    {
        $categories =& $this->getCategories();

        // -> include HTML template and then interate over $categories
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are not "best practices" in this area. Though, there are some, that are more often used then others, and some, that are extremely bad ideas *(unfortunately, these two groups tend to overlap)*.

#### Routing in MVC

While technically not a part of MVC design pattern, when applied to Web, your application needs to know which controller to initialize and what method(s) to call on it.

Doing `explode()` to gather this sort of information is a bad idea. It is both hard to debug and  maintain. A much better solution is to use regular expressions.

Basically you end up having a list of routes, that contain a regular expression and some fallback values. You loop through that list and on fists match extract the data and apply default values, where data was missing.

This approach also frees you to have much wider possibilities for order of parameters.

To make the solution easier to use, you can also add functionality, that turns a *notation* string into a regular expression.

For example (taken from some unit-test, that I have):

- notation:     `test[/:id]` 
  expression: `#^/test(:?/(?P<id>[^/\.,;?\n]+))?$#`
- notation:     `[[/:minor]/:major]` 
  expression: `#^(:?(:?/(?P<minor>[^/\.,;?\n]+))?/(?P<major>[^/\.,;?\n]+))?$#`
- notation:     `user/:id/:nickname` 
  expression: `#^/user/(?P<id>[^/\.,;?\n]+)/(?P<nickname>[^/\.,;?\n]+)$#`

While creating such a generator will not be all that easy, it would be quite reusable. IMHO the time invested in making it would be well spent. Also, the use of `(?P<key>expression)` construct in regular expressions provides you with a very useful array of key-value pairs from the matched route.

#### Menus and MVC

The decision about which menu item to highlight as `active` should always be the responsibility of current view instance.

More complicated issue is where the information, that is necessary for making such decision, comes from. There are two source if data that are available to a view instance: information that was passed to view by controller and data, that view requested from model layer.

> <sub>The controller in MVC takes the user's input and, based on this input, it changes the state of current view and model layer, by passing said values. Controller should **not** be extracting information from model layer.</sub>

IMHO, the better approach in this case is to relay on model layer for information about both menu content and the currently active element in it. While it's possible to both hardcode the currently active element in view and relay on controllers passed informations, MVC is usually used in large scale application, where such practices would end up hurting you.

> <sub>The view in MVC design pattern is not a dumb template. It's a structure, that is responsible for UI logic. In context of Web that would mean creating a response from multiple template, when necessary, or sometimes just simply sending an HTTP location header.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the info @teresko! (You are the one who inspired me to take a step back and do the rewrite, from my other question). But I'm still confused. Say I have one controller method for each route, using regex as you suggest. Each view that they call will ultimately 'extend' nav.php. So where do I define the active link? Do I define the variable in each controller, before it `include`s nav.php?

Comment: @SamSelikoff , actually it should be *"at least one controller per route"*. Controller's method is one of parameters that you extract from that route, which would mean that each route can service multiple methods of controller(s).

Comment: @SamSelikoff , as for the views, it should be that most of the views (ones that produce HTML response) use the `'navigation.php'` template (alongside with other templates). The active line you compute in the view and assign to the navigation [template](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html). This has nothing to do with controllers. Also, it might be a good idea to define a view class, which contains the functionality for working with navigation, which then every other view extends.

Comment: I have four views, one for each chart (month_over_month, cdu_tracker, etc.). Are you saying in month_over_month.php (the view for month_over_month), at the top I put `$active_chart = 'month_over_month'`, and then when I `include 'navigation.php'` it will know which link to make active? This is exactly how I have it currently set up, it just seems to violate DRY - manually typing in `$current_link = ` in every new view, instead of making it dynamic using the parsing. This is the essence of my question.

Comment: Also, since I have main nav and sub-nav, in two of those four templates I'd also have to write `$current_category = '25th_monitoring'` and in the other two `$current_category = 'internet_connectivity'`. Again, seems redundant. But it also doesn't seem like it's appropriate for the controller to handle, which is the only way I see out of it.

Comment: MVC is not a pattern for people who are still using *Include Based Programming*. Learn OOP. And why do you keep writing some crap about controllers?

Comment: Are you talking about using autoload?

Comment: Also, even [this PHP ActiveRecord library](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Quick_Start) shows a `require` statement in its quick start.

Comment: That library is a horrible library, which breaks ever SOLID principle, uses error suppression on regular basis and as **no** protection against injections in MySQL. Why would you hold something that flawed up as "example"?